# Manually inserting a view

Tags: ember.js

I am using a third party library typeaheadjs for an ajax drop down.

I want to render an ember view in each dropdown element, typeahead supports a suggestion hook for this.  I need it to be a propper `Ember.Handlebars` binding because sometimes my ember-data models displayKey will require multiple requests to the server as all my model relationships are `{ async : true }`

```
            suggestion: function(model){ //this hook is part of the typeahead api
                var view = Ember.View.create({
                    model : model,
                    template: Ember.Handlebars.compile('Hello {{model.id}}')
                }).createElement();

                return view.element; //need to return the html tag to render within each <li>
            },
```

`model` is an ember-data model.  The return element needs to be the html to insert into each `<li>` tag.  The following works but the binding `{{model.id}}` is never rendered, I just get `Hello`.

Any ideas why?  I guess I am not running a function that will kick off the bindings or something.

Comment: What version of Ember are you using? Do you have the ability to try HTMLBars?

Comment: @oren Ember:1.8.1. yes, once ember-cli supports html bars I can upgrade if that will help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default context of the compiled template is the view's controller. So replace `model : model` with `controller : model`.

Also you can access view's properties from template in following way:

```
'Hello {{view.model.id}}'
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked, however, I needed to use it like this `'Hello {{id}}'`

Comment: since I am creating my view manually will I need manually cleanup anything? Typeahead will remove the DOM element automatically.